# Java Fonts, CodePoints, Characters

Tags: java, fonts

### Aside

I'm not sure if this is a Java or a Font question, however, I'm using the java.awt.Font class.

### Context

I am using the java.awt.Font class to draw glyphs to the screen. There are functions that allow me to pass it a character to draw. There are functions that allow me to pass it a code point to draw.

### Question

What is the relation between (char ch) and (int codepoint) for characters that are a-z, A-Z, 0-9? Does some standard guarantee that for these alphanumeric characters, the code point value is just the char's ascii value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codepoint is the new lingo equivalent to your old "ASCII value". Since modern encodings go way beyond ASCII's 7 bits, another word had to be coined. But most encodings have the same first 127 characters/codepoints as ASCII - so you're safe here, unless you're dealing with exotic IBM encodings ;-)

Comment: This is just incorrect. It was never even historically true that _"Codepoint is the new lingo equivalent to your old "ASCII value""_.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is a 16 bit Unicode character. One `char` can represent any Unicode character between `\u0000` to `\uffff`, and all of [those characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_Controls_and_Basic_Latin) fall in that range. The reason there are methods that take `char` and others that take [code points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) is because Unicode actually allocates space for 1,114,112 characters, and `char`, being a 16 bit primitive, can only represent the first 65,536 of those.